# Android exclude file from build in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, build

I have an Android project, which I'm working on in Eclipse.  There are no special requirements, however I do have a couple of files in the project which I do not want/need to include into the final build, yet I do want to keep them where they are. They are all java source files and are all in the same package.  There are no files in that package, which I do need to include - so I can safely skip that whole package from build.

So, to my question: is there a way in Eclipse to exclude a package (or an individual file for that matter) from the build when the android app is built?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Eclipse right click on a file (or package) in the Package Explorer. There should be a Build Path > Exclude option

Comment: i'm not entirely sure android uses eclipse preferences for excludes in builds

Comment: Is there a similar way to handle this for other files such as raw resources or assets used in debugging as well perhaps?

Comment: @Jay Snayder I'm not sure about that, but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9289232/1133144) question will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Go to eclipse File->new->Other->Faceted Project->Give project name
and add it to a working set if u want

Eclipse will not build that project or working set

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Did you notice that the question is over 3 years old?  I switched to using AndroidStudio long time ago.

Comment: Just someone in case someone needs who is using eclipse in general

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the right perspective. I just ran into a similar problem and was getting really frustrated because I could not exclude any files. Turns out, before I went on vaca, I was fiddling around with PHP perspective and never changed it back.